# What are all the ways of setting the actual type on the class' type parameter

Tags: java, generics

In generic types there is the parameter on the class like:

```
public class Box<T> {
```

This `T` can be used inside the class.

What are all the ways to set the actual type on this type parameter?

I know about these two:

- instantiating `Box` with exact parameter `new Box<Integer>`
- calling a static method with exact parameter `Box<Integer>.some_method()`

Are these the only ways? If not, please explain the remaining ones.

Comment: Why do you need a list? Is this some sort of weird interview question?

Comment: It is not. I'm trying to understand what are all the ways to "concretize" this type.

Comment: Anything that contains `Box<ActualType>`. Variable declarations, function return types. New expressions and static method calls, as you found out, although I believe for the static method call, the compiler will warn you that it has no effect. I still think it's a weird question.

Comment: If you can post this as an answer, with example of Variable declarations and function return types, as I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: If there's going to be an answer to this question, it should be authoritative with references to the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). Or maybe here's a chance to answer you own question and become more familiar with the internal details of Java?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not considering "concretization" of method type parameter, just of the class type parameter. I think there should not be many cases.